# Render box and contents dynamically from dataframe in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on a dashboard and I want to use a data frame to generate the boxes and descriptions. I can use lapply to make the boxes, but I can't figure out how to pull the description from the data frame. So far I have (without the descriptions):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dataset <- data.frame("title" = c("A","B","C"), "description" = c("Info about box A", "Info about box B","Info about box C"), "data" = c(1:3))

ui <- fluidPage(      
  titlePanel("Dynamic Boxes"),      
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("boxes")
  )
)

dataset <- data.frame("title" = c("A","B","C"), "description" = c("Stuff about box A", "Stuff about box B","Stuff about box C"), "data" = c(1:3))


server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    lapply(dataset[,'title'], function(a) {
      
      box(title = a, p("say stuff here"))
    })
  })
}
```

I can't figure out the correct logic to pull in the descriptions.

I've tried mapply:

```
server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    mapply(function(x,y) {
      
      box(title = x, p(y)
      )
    }, x = dataset[,'title'], y = dataset[,'description']
  )
  })
}
```

but I don't know what I'm doing. Can you help?

Edit:
I can get the dashboard to work using the dummy data above using `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` and with `lapply`

```
server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    lapply(dataset[,'title'], function(a) {
      
      box(title = a, p(dataset[dataset$title==a,2]))
    })
  })
}
```

But I have been unable to get it to work with real data, and am having trouble replicating the issue with the "dummy" data.

My real data lies on a server in a database.

Comment: I am also not getting an error with `dataset3` in this example, I am having trouble replicating the issue with dummy data, maybe the problem is within the real dataset?

Comment: I found the issue! The dataset has multiple non-breaking spaces utf character <U+00A0> removing these fixed the problem. The app works as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was correct with `mapply` you need to include `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` so that it returns a list.

```
server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    mapply(function(x,y) {
      box(title = x, p(y)
      )
    }, x = dataset[,'title'], y = dataset[,'description'], SIMPLIFY = FALSE
    )
  })
}
```

Or use `Map` which always returns a list.

```
server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    Map(function(x,y) box(title = x, p(y)), dataset$title, dataset$description)
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great for the "dummy" data frame, but I am getting an error when I try to use real data. In one case when I use read.csv, I can get the boxes to populate correctly, but when I try to pull the data from a database or even using read_csv, the app crashes. It will pop up for a second and then crash. Do you have any ideas? Could it be a clash or something to do with tibbles?

Comment: I tried that too and have the same results, unfortunately

Comment: I am having trouble providing and example, because the issue may lie within the dataset because I haven't figured out how to replicate the problem I am seeing.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    lapply(dataset[,'title'], function(a) {
      
      box(title = a, p(dataset[dataset$title==a,2]))
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This works great, but like the suggestion from Ronak, the app crashes when pulling data from a database. In one case when I use read.csv, I can get the boxes to populate correctly, but when I try to pull the data from a database or even using read_csv, the app crashes. It will pop up for a second and then crash. Do you have any ideas? Could it be a clash or something to do with tibbles?

Comment: I found the issue, it was caused by utf characters in the dataset; specifically, <U+00A0> non-breaking white space.